# What permissions must be granted for applets to write temporary files?

Tags: java, security, file, permissions, applet

We're developing an applet and need it to be able to read/write files in the user's temporary files directory (e.g. C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Local Settings\Temp).

The applet is signed, the user clicks the 'allow' option on applet startup, and the Java Control Panel has "Allow user to grant permissions to signed content" and "Allow user to grant permissions to content from an untrusted authority" enabled.

However, on startup, we get a SecurityException:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to create temporary file
at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(Unknown Source)
at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
at com.jniwrapper.util.AppletHelper.b(SourceFile:104)
at com.jniwrapper.util.AppletHelper.a(SourceFile:79)
at com.jniwrapper.util.AppletHelper.b(SourceFile:50)
at com.jniwrapper.util.AppletHelper.init(SourceFile:122)
at com.x.Y.init(Y.java:31)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to create temporary file
```

If we edit the java.policy file to grant all to everything then the applet works OK but this is clearly insecure. What minimal permissions must we grant to allow the applet to read/write/create files in the user's temporary files directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the policy file is kinda ok for testing but you should not be relying on it for your finished code, especially when granting a file permission, it is dangerous.

To interact with files you need to do the following.

1. Sign your jar - tons of tutorials like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html), you can just do a self signed one.
2. Add the file creation code to a privileged block here is an example

   ```
   File myFile = (File) AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
   public Object run() 
   {
       return new File("C:\\MyFolder\\MyFile");
   }

   });
   ```

Comment: Do you know the policy file entry for this permission? I have code that I cannot change and I need to apply this policy.

Comment: Should be something like this,   

grant {
      permission java.io.FilePermission "/directory", "read, write";
  };

if you do not want to leave this wide open which you shouldnt as its a gaping security hole, you should sign the jar and do a grant principle or at least grant codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Got to that same point. To grant the permission as close as possible to what is needed minimally, you can grant a `FilePermission` on `${java.io.tmpdir}\-` with actions `read,write,delete`. This worked for me.

Of course you have to replace the `${...}` by the value of the system property `java.io.tmpdir`. This property is used by `java.io.File.createTempFile`.

**Note:** With `someDir\-` you grant recursive access to all subdirs of the `someDir` path. At this point you can use `someDir\*` but I haven't tested it.

If you use policy files to grant permissions there is a good chance that those files already support referencing system properties. But google that again to be sure. If you use a custom policy implementation you can easily create the permission `java.io.FilePermission`.