# Signed Java applet permission

Tags: java, image, security, screenshot, signed-applet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting up policies for an Applet embedded in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313672/setting-up-policies-for-an-applet-embedded-in-html)

I created a simple Java applet to get the screenshot of the website. I signed the jar and it seems it is pretty much verified.

```
         410 Fri Sep 14 13:20:34 EEST 2012 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
         376 Fri Sep 14 13:20:36 EEST 2012 META-INF/SIGNER.SF
         830 Fri Sep 14 13:20:36 EEST 2012 META-INF/SIGNER.RSA
           0 Fri Sep 14 13:20:36 EEST 2012 META-INF/
           0 Fri Sep 14 13:20:36 EEST 2012 screencaptureapplet/
sm       615 Fri Sep 14 13:20:36 EEST 2012 screencaptureapplet/CaptureFrame$1.class
sm     17311 Fri Sep 14 13:20:36 EEST 2012 screencaptureapplet/CaptureFrame.class

  s = signature was verified
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope

jar verified.
```

however it doesnt work on my website. it says:

```
access denied (java.awt.AWTPermission createRobot)
```

and what is awkward is that it fails at the very first line of my function which is

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
```

does anyone out there know way to fix this issue?

Comment: If I run the file directly from NetBeans, it takes a screenshot. There is absolutely no problem with the code...

Comment: briliant read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313672/setting-up-policies-for-an-applet-embedded-in-html

Comment: Are you prompted to accept the digitally signed code?  If not restart the browser and flush the class cache.