# Granting permission for Java Applet to write to system

Tags: java, applet, policy, sql-grant

I need to grant my applet the ability to save to a file. I tried to make a java.policy file to accomplish this and it's not working. Below is the code for the policy file and for the method that saves to the data file.

```
public void save()
{
    try
    {
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("_stats.dat"));
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            out.write(a[i].trim());
            out.newLine();
        }
        out.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException f)
    {
        System.out.println(f.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException i)
    {
        System.out.println(i.getMessage());
    }
}

grant {
    permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "write";
};
```

They are both in the same directory and it appears that the save method is not recognizing the policy file or something. Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at this previous post:

[How to write to a file in applets in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388523/how-to-write-to-a-file-in-applets-in-java)

Make sure your applet is signed.

Comment: I'm planning on running the applet on my local machine (through appletviewer), not through a web browser. Is there anyway around not signing it because my professor views it through an appletviewer and not the html file.

Comment: *"my professor views it through an appletviewer"*  Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: An applet launched free floating using JWS can be unsigned, and still access the local disks using the file services of the JNLP API.  But then, the JNLP API also offers a `PersistenceService`.  Here is a [demo of the `PersistenceService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#ps).  Of course, that is 'for the moment' until Oracle raises the default security level of Java..