# Output of an applet is written into a file

Tags: java

This is my assignment program: write information from an applet into a file. My program is getting complied and running as well , but the file is not being created.
Can anyone please tell me why,I will appreciate the help!

```
enter code here
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class info extends Applet implements ActionListener 
{
String str;
FileWriter f;
TextField id,name;
Label e,i,n;
String msg;
public void init()
{
   e=new Label("Employee info");
   add(e);
   i=new Label("Employee id");
   add(i);
   id=new TextField(10);
   add(id);
   n=new Label("name:");
   add(n);
   name=new TextField(10);
   add(name);

 Button submit= new Button("submit");
 Button reset= new Button("reset");
 id.addActionListener(this);
 name.addActionListener(this);
 add(submit);
 add(reset);
 submit.addActionListener(this);
 reset.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
```

{
       String str = ae.getActionCommand();

```
     if(str.equals("submit")) 
    {  
        showStatus("Data Submitted Successfully");
    }
    else if(str.equals("reset")) 
    {
        id.setText("");
        name.setText("");

    }
    repaint();
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
```

{

```
    g.drawString("id: "+id.getText(),6,150);
    g.drawString("Name: " + name.getText(), 6, 200);
```

}

```
 public void print() throws IOException
{
str=id.getText()+" "+name.getText(); 
f =new FileWriter("e.txt");
f.write(str);
}
```

}

```
class output extends info
   {

public static void main(String...s)throws Exception
    {

       output obj=new output();
       obj.print();
    }
  }
```

Comment: `void main()` is what gets called in Java _applications_, not applets.

Comment: You should make the call to `print()` from your `init()` method, or somewhere else where the applet code will actually reach.  Better yet, stop using applets as they have been deprecated (i.e. they are an obsolete technology).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write to a file in applets in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388523/how-to-write-to-a-file-in-applets-in-java)