# Create a File object in memory from a string in Java

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have a function that accepts File as an argument. I don't want to create/write a new File (I don't have write access to filesystem) in order to pass my string data to the function. I should add that the String data don't exist in a file (so I cannot read my data from a file).

Can I use Streams and "cast" them to File objects?

Comment: Can you link/post the code that takes a `File` object?  As the answers have stated, a `File` object is like a reference to a location in the filesystem, and so would be hard to simulate without an actual file.  If, however, your function took a `FileReader` or a `FileInputStream`, you could easily modify the code to accept non-file input.

Comment: Memory mapped files can be your choice. These are special files in Java which allows Java program to access contents  directly from memory. For details please go through this link : http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/memorymapped-file-and-io-in-java.html

Answer (score 51, accepted):

No; instances of class `File` represent a path in a filesystem. Therefore, you can use that function only with a file. But perhaps there is an overload that takes an `InputStream` instead?

Answer (score 82):

Usually when a method accepts a file, there's another method nearby that accepts a stream. If this isn't the case, the API is badly coded. Otherwise, you can use temporary files, where permission is usually granted in many cases. If it's applet, you can [request write permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369365/what-permissions-must-be-granted-for-applets-to-write-temporary-files).

An example:

```
try {
    // Create temp file.
    File temp = File.createTempFile("pattern", ".suffix");

    // Delete temp file when program exits.
    temp.deleteOnExit();

    // Write to temp file
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));
    out.write("aString");
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: Cannot request write permission (it's Google AppEngine)

Answer (score 12):

A [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object in Java is a representation of a path to a directory or file, not the file itself.  You don't need to have write access to the filesystem to create a `File` object, you only need it if you intend to actually write to the file (using a [FileOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) for example)

Comment: If you need to pass a file to an external API, you need an actual file - passing an "empty" File object won't work.

Answer (score 8):

The `File` class represents the "idea" of a file, not an actual handle to use for I/O.  This is why the `File` class has a `.exists()` method, to tell you if the file exists or not.  (How can you have a `File` object that doesn't exist?)

By contrast, constructing a `new FileInputStream(new File("/my/file"))` gives you an actual stream to read bytes from.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileReader r = new FileReader(file);
```

Use a file reader load the file and then write its contents to a string buffer.

[example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/LoadatextfilecontentsasaString.htm)

The link above shows you an example of how to accomplish this. As other post to this answer say to load a file into memory you do not need write access as long as you do not plan on making changes to the actual file.